# Xaml C# How to add corner radius each side of two columns, with Gridsplitter

Tags: gridsplitter, cornerradius

(I'm french...sorry ;-) )

```
<Grid x:Name="grid2" Margin="0,5,0,5">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="3" />
                <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Border x:Name="b3" BorderBrush="DarkOrange" CornerRadius="8,0,0,8" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" Background="DarkOrange">
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" TextAlignment="Center" Background="Transparent" >Partie Gauche</TextBlock>
            </Border>
            <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Background="Red"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ShowsPreview="True" ResizeDirection="Columns" />
            <Border x:Name="b4" BorderBrush="DarkGreen" CornerRadius="0,8,8,0" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" Background="DarkGreen">
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" TextAlignment="Center" Background="Darkgreen" >Partie Droite</TextBlock>
            </Border>
</Grid>
```

[with CornerRadius Grid.Column="0" and Grid.Column="2"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sdvbd.jpg)

[without CornerRadius Grid.Column="2"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJtpy.jpg)

I do not put corners on the Grid.Column="2", keeping the layout.
Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? http://www.rollthunder.com/softwarethatdoesntsuck/Images/img4E.jpg

Comment: Sorry I forgot the link to the code http://familyshow.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#4.0/Source/FamilyShow/MainWindow.xaml

Comment: Yes absolutely! With a central gridsplitter....
I do not understand the behavior of the Grid.Column="2"...

Comment: Thank you, I'll watch this ...

Comment: I looked at the code. There are no GridSplitter...
In fact I wish to have only four rounded corners...with GridSlitter in the middle.

Comment: I remember doing this few years back. I can't find my code though. I suggest downloading and running the family.show code and experimenting with it by removing the parts you dont need. It helped me understand how it worked and where to add the gridsplitter.